# How to access ImageView that is in a Layout Integer in a ViewPager

Tags: java, android-studio, integer, android-viewpager

I made an Adapter for my ViewPager which gets its values from an Integer in my MainActivity. The problem is I can't access the Image view inside that layout. Here you can see my codes:

///*** The Java Model:

```
public class ZModel {
    final Integer alphabetViews;

    public ZModel(Integer alphabetViews) {
        this.alphabetViews = alphabetViews;
    }

    public Integer getAlphabetViews(){
        return alphabetViews;
    }
}
```

///*** The Java Adapter:

```
final Context mContext;
    final ArrayList<ZModel> zModels;

    public ZAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ZModel> zModels){
        this.mContext = context;
        this.zModels = zModels;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(zModels.get(position).getAlphabetViews(),container,false);
        container.addView(layout);

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return zModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
```

///***Main Activity 2:

```
if ((Integer)imageView.getTag()==R.drawable.clock1) {
            alphabetViews = new Integer[]{R.layout.letter_blue, R.layout.letter_green, R.layout.letter_pink, R.layout.letter_red, R.layout.letter_yellow};

           ///***I wish to access the ImageViews which are in the above Layouts
        }

        if ((Integer)imageView.getTag()==R.drawable.clock2){
            alphabetViews = new Integer[]{R.layout.letter_yellow, R.layout.letter_red, R.layout.letter_pink, R.layout.letter_green, R.layout.letter_blue};
        }
```

///*** The (letter_blue.xml) details

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_test1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clock1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see the ViewPager is working with Activites and it gets its values from an Integer and I can easily swipe it and there's no problem with it, just want to access the imageview which is in almost every layout.